# Luggage storage in Santa Cruz das Flores

Tags: luggage-storage, portugal, azores

My plan is to arrive in the city at 11:15 AM, and to stay in Fajã Grande on the other side of the island. The first [bus](http://www.utc.pt//client/files/0000000001/1245.jpg) that I can catch leaves at 5:50 PM, which gives me over 6 hours to chill around the city.

Is there any public place in or around the airport to leave a large backpack during the day? I couldn't find any info on [the Flores airport website](https://www.aeroportoflores.pt/en/flw/home).

Answer (score 1):

There's luggage storage in INATEL Flores Hotel (10 minute walk from the airport)